# [APEX]: Way to iterate over method parameters

Tags: apex, parameters, method, function

I have a method that accepts 4 parameters. I want to do the same action for every parameter if it's not null. Is there a way to iterate over all parameters rather than building if blocks?

So for example is it possible to do something like this:

```
public static void myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4) {
    for (Parameter param: params) {
        if (param != null) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
public static void myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4) {
        if (param1 != null) {
            // do something
        }
        if (param2 != null) {
            // do something
        }
        if (param3 != null) {
            // do something
        }
        if (param4 != null) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any possibility of turning your 4 parameters into a single `List<String>`?

Comment: Any reason you can't pass in a list of strings for processing in this manner?

Comment: @DerekF That's a good point but what if one of the parameters is say an Integer. I guess I can do List<sObject> then.

Comment: @DerekF can you post your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: If you plan on having different typed parameters then you could also make an overloaded method which accepts the types of params you want to "do something" to, and call the respective overloaded method once for each param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Derek F said, you can either change method so that it accepts a list (or a map).

You can always do the following:

```
public static void myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4) {
    List<String> paramList = new List<String>{param1, param2, param3, param4};
    for (String param : paramList){
        if(String.isNotBlank(param)){   //(param != null)
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `new List<String>{'realstring1',null,'realstring2'}` may give an error if you're passing in a null value

Comment: It does not throw an error, I had tested it in execute anonymous. I wouldn't normally initialize a list with null values but I think for this question the answer suffices.